# coffeescript class variable visibility

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript, visibility

I have got something like this:

```
class @Cat
    defaults:
        name: ''
        weight: 0
    constructor: ( @options ) ->
        $.each @.defaults, (key, val) =>
          @options[key] = val unless @options.hasOwnProperty(key)
```

i wanna use

```
$.each (array, callback), (index, value) ->
```

instead of

```
$.each (array, callback), (index, value) =>
```

and use the class variable `@options`, but obviously `@` refers to the array.
Solution?

Comment: Solution is *not* to use `->` over `=>`? Why don't you want the fat arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're having trouble accessing the `options` that belong to the instance of the class, correct ?

And you know this is because [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) sets `this` to an object-wrapped version of the val variable, so `@options` does not work in that callback.

In my example below, the slight change is that I've closed the `each` callback over the variable `opts`, which will allow your loop to refer to the contents of `@options` even though `this` has been changed.

```
class Cat
  defaults:
    name: 'tabby'
    weight: 5

  constructor: (@options) ->
    opts = @options
    $.each @defaults, (key, val) ->
      opts[key] = val unless opts.hasOwnProperty(key)

c = new Cat(name: 'fluffy')
console.log c.options
```

Notice, no double arrow is needed :) In your case, the double arrow wouldn't have hurt since you were accessing the variable `val` instead of using `@` to refer to the value of the current iteration, but you're right to try to get rid of `=>` when not absolutely necessary.

Try it at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chicagogrooves/72fa3/

That said, I'd like to mention that for the case of overwriting defaults, you could use [jquery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) instead of manually writing your loop. This is a common enough thing to do that it is part of many libraries, not something you need to write by hand usually. But I wanted to explain more thoroughly since double arrows and `this` are good concepts to know.

Comment: this is what i have do but i thought for another solution. I stick it anyway cause probably is the only solution